# Create complex Geometry / Path with multiple colors [Silverlight]

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, silverlight, geometry

Currently i have this figure created and displayed (Yellow color is the figure, black is background):

[image]

The information about the figure is stored in XML, and loaded into the system on startup.

```
 <Part Name="Test" Description="Test description" Geometry="M 0,0 L 20,0 L 20,20 L 0,20 Z M 0,40 L 20,40 L 20,60 L 0,60 Z M 80,0 L 100,0 L100,20 L 80,20 Z M 80,40 L 100,40 L 100,60 L 80,60 Z M 20,0 L 80,0 L 80,60 L 20,60 Z" Color="Yellow" Height="60" Width="100"/>
```

The information is then used to populate a class that has:

Size, Geometry and Color properties in addition to the other less relevant data such as Name, Description etc.

I display this in a XAML view using a Canvas with a Path:

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Description}">
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Data="{Binding Geometry}" Stroke="{Binding StrokeColor}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="{Binding Size.Width}" Height="{Binding Size.Height}"/>
</Canvas>
```

This all works fine. But a requirement has come up so that the four outwards facing blocks of the shape have to be of a different color.

[image]

Since this is currently one Path, it can only have one Color. And at the same time as far as i've been able to tell there is no Color available for Geometry.

So i need to split my original Geometry into multiple small geometries. Then create multiple Paths from that, and combine it all together somehow to be able to display it properly.

Maybe a XML structure like this:

```
<Part Name="Test" etc>
    <Geometries>
        <GeometryPart Geometry="M 0,0 L 20,0 L 20,20 L 0,20" Color="White">
        <GeometryPart Geometry="M 0,40 L 20,40 L 20,60 L 0,60" Color="White">
        <GeometryPart Geometry="M 0,40 L 20,40 L 20,60 L 0,60" Color="White">
        <GeometryPart Geometry="M 0,40 L 20,40 L 20,60 L 0,60" Color="White">
        <GeometryPart Geometry="M 0,40 L 20,40 L 20,60 L 0,60" Color="Yellow">
     </Geometries>
</Part
```

I have been using this idea as a basis for trying to create something directly in the XAML view / code behind to create an example figure and get it displayed. But after going at it for awhile i still havent found any good solution.

Anyone got any suggestions / pointers for me?

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: Whats the question exactly?

Comment: Is it neccesary to do in that way or I can explain you how to do in a design software and extract the XAML?

Comment: Sorry if the question itself is a bit vauge. I need to be able to create and display the second shape (Yellow rectangle, with four white squares). 

Information about how the shape looks has to be stored in XML as part of the <Part> tag.

Then i need a class that can hold this data (Name, Description etc + information about how the figure looks). So that i can data bind to a collection of this new class in my view and have them display the figure assosicated with it.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for you is to simply use a `LinearGradientBrush` to show yellow in just the centre of your `Path`. Take this simple example using a `Rectangle`:

```
<Rectangle Width="500" Height="250" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.25001" />
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.74999" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This is what it appears like:

[image]

Comment: Nice trick! Thankfully I was able to amend my paths to split them vertically, with "left color" and "right color".